# Class with constants inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

For a gpib device interface in Python (using the ctypes module), I group constants used by this device in my class:

```
class IbcnfOPTConst(object):
    ''' 
    The following constants are used for the second parameter of the  ibconfig() function.
    They are the "option" selection codes.
    '''
    IbcPAD             = 0x0001  #// Primary Address
    IbcSAD             = 0x0002  #// Secondary Address
    IbcTMO             = 0x0003  #// Timeout Value
    IbcEOT             = 0x0004  #// Send EOI with last data byte?
    ...
```

Another function needs almost the same constants but updated with new ones and the old ones now have a different meaning, so I define a new class as inheritance of existing one:

```
class IbAskConst(IbcnfOPTConst):
    ''' Constants that can be used 
        when calling the ibask() function.
    '''
    IbaPAD             = IbcnfOPTConst.IbaSAD
    IbaTMO             = IbcnfOPTConst.IbcTMO
    IbaEOT             = IbcnfOPTConst.IbcEOT
    IbaPPC             = IbcnfOPTConst.IbcPPC
    ....
    IbaSerialNumber    = 0x0023
    IbaBNA             = 0x0200  #// A device's access board
```

Is there a better way regarding inheritance to use constants in child class?

Comment: I already answered here, but I realized that this question should've probably been posted to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). That's where you should usually post when you have a fully working code that you're looking to improve, StackOverflow is for issues with your code.

Comment: Are you adding the last two constants or changing them? Also is the primary address of the child actually the secondary address of the parent, or was that a typo?

Comment: in ni4882.h are defined: 
//constants for ibconfig:
#define IbcPAD             0x0001  // Primary Address
#define IbcSAD             0x0002  // Secondary Address
//constants for ibask()
#define IbaPAD             IbcPAD
#define IbaSAD             IbcSAD
...
#define IbaSerialNumber    0x0023
So from here ideea with base class and derived one( just meaning for second function to use renamed constants)